# Let $f(x)=6x(1-x)$ a density function which is the probability of $P(\mu-2\sigma < X < \mu+2\sigma)$

Tags: probability

Let $f(x)=6x(1-x)$ a density function which is the probability of $P(\mu-2\sigma < X < \mu+2\sigma)$

> Note:
>   
> $\mu$= Expected value.
>   
> $\sigma$= Standart deviation.

**My work:**

Note $\mu=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \! xf(x)dx=6[x^2|_{0}^1 -x^3|^1_{0}]=0$

And $Var[X]=0$ then $\sigma=0$

Here i'm too stuck because $P(0<X<0)$ and that doesn't have sense. Can someone help me?

Comment: Always mention the support of the densities, without which they have no meaning. Presumably, here $P(0<X<1)=1$ which would make $X$ a beta variable of the first kind.

Answer (score 0):

If f(x) is a frequency distribution:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx = 1$$

Which is clearly not the case if $f(x) = 6x(1-x)$

But could be the case if $f(x) = 0$ outside of some interval.

$$\int_{a}^{b} 6x - 6x^2 \ dx\\
3x^2 - 2x^3|_{a}^{b} = 1$$

And one suitable interval is $[0,1]$

For the mean:

$$\mu = \int_0^1 xf(x)\ dx\\
\int_0^1 6x^2-6x^3\\
2x^3 - \frac 32 x^4 |_0^1 = \frac 12$$

And the variance:

$$\sigma^2 = \int_0^1 x^2f(x)\ dx$$

And I will leave it to you to complete the integration.